# Error coercing raster with one non-NA value to SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: raster, r, sp

I'm getting a strange error when trying to convert a raster with only 1 non-NA pixel to SpatialPixelsDataFrame.

```
r0 <- raster( matrix( 1, 1,1))
as(r0, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

And it doesn't seem to depend on the size of the raster

```
r1 <- raster( matrix( c(1, NA), 1,2))
as(r1, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

```
r2 <- raster( matrix( c(1, rep(NA,99)), 10,10))
as(r1, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘coordinates’ for signature ‘"numeric"’

Yet when I include 2 or more non-NA pixels ...

```
r3 <- raster( matrix( c(1,1, rep(NA,98) ), 10, 10))

as(r3, 'SpatialPixelsDataFrame')
```

Everything works fine.

```
Object of class SpatialPixelsDataFrame
Object of class SpatialPixels
Grid topology:
   cellcentre.offset cellsize cells.dim
s1              0.05      0.1        10
s2              0.05      0.1        10
SpatialPoints:
        x    y
[1,] 0.05 0.95
[2,] 0.05 0.85
Coordinate Reference System (CRS) arguments: NA
...blah blah blah
```

I realize this is a boundary case, but any idea what is going on here?

I'm getting this error only occasionally as part of a larger automated process, so it would be great if there was a way to convert my 1-pixel raster to a SPDF without an elaborate hack.

Comment: Thanks for reporting (and to @Spacdeman for passing this on). Fixed in the development version.

Comment: @PolyGeo - don't know why this question was closed as a bug report, it was a user getting an error that turned out to be a bug. User did not know it was a bug at the time.

Comment: @Spacedman  It is closed as a bug report because that is how [it appears to have been resolved](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314472/error-coercing-raster-with-one-non-na-value-to-spatialpixelsdataframe?noredirect=1#comment511191_314472) and that resolution has even been accepted by the asker.  Both the question and answer have upvotes that keep it on the site so being closed does not affect its visibility to future searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug in the `raster` package. If your raster has only one non-zero cell, then this line:

https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/3e33743a12d2c8f407a4afc45dabc9ae9b1ae5fe/R/coerce.R#L47

```
 sp <- SpatialPoints(v[,1:2], proj4string= crs(r))
```

will drop a dimension at `v[,1:2]`. Changing to `v[,1:2, drop=FALSE]` should fix it. There's a few other places that this might happen also.

I'll report it via email to the maintainer....